# Group By Sum in django model field

Tags: django

```
class Model1(models.Model):

    model1_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    model1_sum = models.IntegerField()

class Model2(models.Model):
    model2_name = CharField(max_length=200)
    model2_number = CharField(max_length=200)
    model2_super_sum
```

In `model2_number` will be multichoice list with `model1_number` `values(example, 1,2,5)`. I want in `model_super_sum` get the amount of `model1_sum`.

I try sql, but bad...

Comment: why don't you just have a foreign key to `Model1` ?

Comment: how? in model2_name may be more than one value - this's list

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do. why do you want properties from `Model1` on `Model2`? how is `model2_name` involved?

Comment: Example, in Model1 - № of stores(warehouses) - in SUM - amount of product. In Model2 list of departament (it consists of stores) - in Super_SUM - amount of product in stores belonging to this departament(model2_name)

Answer (score 0):

As @Anentropic suggested you should have a ForeignKey on `Model1` mapping to `Model2`. It'll make your life much easier.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    model_2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2, related_name="model_1_set")
    sum = models.IntegerField()


class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Then to get the super sum of the Model2, you'd do the following:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Model2.objects.all().annotate(super_sum=Sum('model_1_set__sum'))
```

Note that I removed your number small positive integer field on `Model1` because Django automatically provides you with an auto incrementing integer id.

Comment: I think `Model2.objects.all(super_sum=Sum('model_1_set__sum'))` should read `Model2.objects.annotate(super_sum=Sum('model_1_set__sum'))`

Comment: but where and how I choice model2_number?